# Shiny app not displaying widgets in UI

Tags: javascript, shiny

(this is also posted on [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-dashboard-not-displaying-all-widgets/3682)...)

I’m trying to debug a Shiny app. Most of the app is working fine, but several tabs are not rendering everything now, and I can’t figure out why. (Typically, one or two outputs will render, but the rest will be totally missing.) I’ve turned on shiny.trace, and can see correct-looking payload being sent to the client. Typically, if there are a half-dozen objects being sent to the client, it'll get through several of them but not render the rest (in order). On the client, in the JS console, I can see a bunch of errors that look like this:

```
htmlwidgets.js:475 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
at exports.OutputBinding.shinyBinding.find (htmlwidgets.js:475)
at a (init_shiny.js:15)
at f (init_shiny.js:215)
at Object.exports.bindAll (init_shiny.js:225)
at Object.exports.renderContent (output_binding_html.js:51)
at exports.OutputBinding.renderValue (output_binding_html.js:14)
at exports.OutputBinding.onValueChange (output_binding.js:16)
at OutputBindingAdapter.onValueChange (output_binding_adapter.js:21)
at ShinyApp.receiveOutput (shinyapp.js:350)
at ShinyApp.<anonymous> (shinyapp.js:562)
shinyBinding.find @ htmlwidgets.js:475
a @ init_shiny.js:15
f @ init_shiny.js:215
exports.bindAll @ init_shiny.js:225
exports.renderContent @ output_binding_html.js:51
renderValue @ output_binding_html.js:14
onValueChange @ output_binding.js:16
onValueChange @ output_binding_adapter.js:21
receiveOutput @ shinyapp.js:350
(anonymous) @ shinyapp.js:562
_sendMessagesToHandlers @ shinyapp.js:547
dispatchMessage @ shinyapp.js:533
c.onmessage @ shinyapp.js:112
4app.js:279 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
    at Object.fix (app.js:279)
    at app.js:252
    at dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Chrome 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit) (but also have identical issue on Safari)

Searching around for similar seems to suggest it's likely a Javascript library issue, but I don't know what to do with that information. How do I track down what's causing the front end to fail to render and throw these errors?

Comment: could you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

I've identified the problem! I was using [this trick](http://scottshepard.io/markdown-pages-as-tabs-in-shiny/) to create a documentation page for my app. Unfortunately, Pandoc appears to insert some content into the HTML that conflicts with Shiny. Removing the Pandoc content fixes the problem. (Although I'll need another solution for my documentation page...)